# How to get names of all branches in repository?

Tags: git, typescript, github, probot

For example, I have five branches in the current repository, and their names are: master, branch1, branch2, branch3, and branch4. Use the typescript language for probot build to get these names.

What I have tried:

```
import { Application } from 'probot' 
export = (app: Application) => {
  app.on(`*`, async context => {
    var branchName = context.github.repos.listBranches.name
    var branchName1 = context.github.repos.getBranch.name
    var branchName2 = context.payload.Status.branches.name
    console.log(branchName + "\n")
    // result: bound apiMethod
    console.log(branchName1 + "\n")
    // result: bound apiMethod
    console.log(branchName2 + "\n")
    // result: ERROR event: Cannot read property 'branches' of undefined
  })
}
```

Please explain about what does `bound apiMethod` mean here also.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myRepoID = context.repo({number: context.payload.repository.id})
await context.github.repos.listBranches(myRepoID)
```